# Python generators - float( ( yield ) )?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I am reading the following tutorial about generators in Python
http://excess.org/article/2013/02/itergen2/

It contains the following code:

```
def running_avg():
    "coroutine that accepts numbers and yields their running average"
    total = float((yield))
    count = 1
    while True:
        i = yield total / count
        count += 1
        total += i
```

I don't understand the meaning of `float((yield))`. I thought `yield` was used to "return" a value from a generator. Is this a different use of `yield`?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `yield` can also *recieve*, by sending to the generator:

```
>>> avg_gen = running_avg()
>>> next(avg_gen)  # prime the generator
>>> avg_gen.send(1.0)
1.0
>>> print avg_gen.send(2.0)
1.5
```

Any value passed to the [`generator.send()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) is returned by the `yield` expression. See the [`yield` expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) documentation.

`yield` was made an expression in Python 2.5; before it was just a statement and only produced values for the generator. By making `yield` an expression and adding `.send()` (and other methods to send exceptions as well) generators are now usable as simple [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine); see [PEP 342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) for the initial motivations for this change.

Answer (score 3):

Its an extended `yield` syntax for coroutines

Read this:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/